# How to create a new subscription that removes any previous subscribers C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delegates

I'm studying for an exam and I came across a question I couldn't figure out. It asks to Create a TurnOnRadio method for the Radio class. This method should remove any TV subscribers to the remote control object. I thought I could do this with just = without the += or -=. When I go to do this is says This event  " RemoteControl.channelChange " can only be on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'Remote Control') Any help on accomplishing this task would be appreciated. Code posted below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RemoteControlApp2
{
class RemoteControl
{
    public delegate void ChannelChanged(object remote, RemoteEventsArgs re);
    public event ChannelChanged channelChange;
    private int currentChannel;

    public void ChangeTheCrrentChannel(int newChannel)
    {
        RemoteEventsArgs newRe = new RemoteEventsArgs(newChannel);

        if (channelChange!=null)
        {
            channelChange(this, newRe);
         }
    }
}

class RemoteEventsArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int newChannel;

    public RemoteEventsArgs(int nc)
    {
        this.newChannel = nc;
    }
}

class Television
{
    private int tvChannel;
    //Your code here
    public void TurnOnTV(RemoteControl Remote)
    {
        Remote.channelChange += new RemoteControl.ChannelChanged(TVChannelChanged);
        Console.WriteLine(Remote.ToString() + " is detected");
    }
    public void TurnOffTV(RemoteControl Remote)
    {
        Remote.channelChange -= new RemoteControl.ChannelChanged(TVChannelChanged);
        Console.WriteLine(Remote.ToString() + " is no longer detected");
    }
    public void TVChannelChanged(Object Remote, RemoteEventsArgs nc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The TV channel is changed. New channel is: {0}", nc.newChannel);
    }
}

class Radio
{
    private int radioChannel;
    //Your code here
    public void TurnOnRadio(RemoteControl Remote)
    {
        Remote.channelChange = new RemoteControl.ChannelChanged(TVChannelChanged);
        Console.WriteLine(Remote.ToString() + " is deteceted")
    }
    //May need to write RadioChannelChanged method

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RemoteControl rc = new RemoteControl();
        Television tv = new Television();
        tv.TurnOnTV(rc);
        rc.ChangeTheCrrentChannel(29);
        rc.ChangeTheCrrentChannel(32);
        tv.TurnOffTV(rc);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took out event from public event ChannelChanged channelchange;
So now it is public ChannelChanged channelchange;
Next I finished the radio class and TurnOnRadio method and now that event has been removed I can use = to remove all other subscriptions and now subscribes whatever channel the remote is changed to in main. Radio class code posted below.

```
class Radio
{
    private int radioChannel;
    //Your code here
    public void TurnOnRadio(RemoteControl Remote)
    {
        Remote.channelChange = new RemoteControl.ChannelChanged(RadioChannelChanged);
        //Console.WriteLine(Remote.ToString() + " is deteceted");
    }
    public void RadioChannelChanged(object Remote,RemoteEventsArgs re)
    {
        radioChannel = re.newChannel;
        Console.WriteLine("Radio channel is changed. New channel is :{0}", re.newChannel);
    }
    //May need to write RadioChannelChanged method

}
```